# How can I find sub documents using Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have mongodb DB and use `mongoose`.

It made of the following schema

```
var Schedule = mongoose.Schema({
  StartType: Number,
  StartDateTime: Date,
  CollectionList: [CollectionSchema]
});

var CollectionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  CollectionID: Number,
  CollectionName: String,
  chdata: [ChannelSchema]
});

var ChannelSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  ADChannelName: String,
  ADChannel: Number,
  ADChannelType: Number,
  DisplayColor: String,
  Command: String
});

Schedule = mongoose.model('schedule', ScheduleSchema);
Collection = mongoose.model('collection', CollectionSchema);
Channel = mongoose.model('channel', ChannelSchema);

Schedule.find({}, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

So I can find Schedule but I want find Collection and Channel object.

How can I find them using mongoose?

Comment: Use Aggregation If you need to search inside CollectionSchema  and ChannelSchema object

Comment: You want to find `collection` or `channel`? and you want to find by which attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-deep-populate

```
Schedule.find({}, function (err, schedules) {
   Schedule.deepPopulate(schedules, 'CollectionList.chdata', function (err, users) {
      // now each Schedule document includes CollectionList and each CollectionList includes chdata
   })
})
```